# How to share link on Facebook that open iPad application

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad

We have developed app for iPad that can share some part of the app on Facebook. The scenario is when user opens shared link, it will start our app on iPad. The syntax is myapp:// to open link from iPad browse but the issue is can not share such link on Facebook saying like '...error occured.'. How to share such link on Facebook or alternate way to perform same operation.

Comment: This is a facebook policy. They only allow specific url schemes. You are out of luck.

Comment: That means I can assume we no longer can provide this sort of functionality to the client. right ?

Comment: Well, technically you could share a regular http link, which redirects to a url for your app. You would have to test this however.

Comment: The app will be already installed on client, iPad. Need to open that app through link.

Comment: Instead of sending url in post you can use Facebook AppRequest.